# What username, server and port are specified for IMAP with Gmail using getmail?

Tags: email, archive, imap, gmail, getmail

Looking at github and trying to use their [example](https://github.com/getmail6/getmail6) config file:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat .config/getmail/getmail 

[options]
verbose = 1
delete = false
message_log = ~/.getmail/log
message_log_verbose = true
read_all = false


[retriever]
type = SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever
server = imap.gmail.com
port = 993
username = saunders.nicholas@gmail.com
password = xxx
#mailboxes = ("INBOX")

[destination]
type = Mboxrd
path = ~/GotMail/inbox
user = saunders

 

nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ getmail
getmail version 6.18.4
Copyright (C) 1998-2021 Charles Cazabon and others. Licensed under GNU GPL version 2.
SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever:saunders.nicholas@gmail.com@imap.gmail.com:993:
Configuration error: no such specified user ("getpwnam(): name not found: 'saunders'")
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

Trying getmail to archive old e-mails from gmail.  I've tried a few options with the server, port and username but can't find a combination which works.

The Pine e-mail client works fine with 2FA and using the app password, so fairly certain it's server name, username or something like that.  Logs are empty.

see also:

https://www.bytereef.org/howto/oauth2/getmail.html

where he specifies:

```
type = SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever
server = imap.gmail.com
username = your_account@gmail.com
```

Comment: You didn't mention it, so I'll ask: 'Have you set up your Gmail account w/ 2FA and an **"app password"**?'

Comment: yes, and that's the password represented above by "xxx"; the "app password" works fine from the Alpine e-mail client (was Pine).  I omitted mention of 2FA to *try* and improve the clarity of the question.  I'm reasonably certain it's just the IMAP settings.